# CSS code for select option tag

Tags: html, css, forms

I have an form in my index page where i used same css code for input and select but the problem is that in input tag its working fine as per i want but in the select tag firstly width became little small and in when i am selecting the option its not getting selected though in MAC chrome its working fine but in  windows chrome its not getting selected!!

Please check my code and let me know where i went wrong!

```css
#contact-form input[type="text"],
#contact-form select[type="text"],
#contact-form textarea {
  width: 247px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 16px 10px;
  background: #4f5662;
  border: 1px solid #828fac;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  color: #b6b7b8;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  margin-right: 18px;
}

#contact-form input[type="submit"],
.newsleter-widget input[type="submit"] {
  float: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #8248ac;
  padding: 20px 13px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
}

#contact-form input[type="text"],
#contact-form select[type="text"],
#contact-form2 textarea {
  margin-right: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 94%;
  max-width: 94%;
  margin-bottom: 19px;
  padding: 16px 3%
}

#contact-form textarea,
#contact-form2 textarea {
  height: 110px;
  padding: 8px 3%;
}

#contact-form input[type="submit"],
#contact-form2 input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px 38px;
}
```

```html
<div class="span4">
  <h3>Contact Form</h3>
  <form id="contact-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Phone no">
    <select type="text" name="service">
    <option value="" selected >Select Services</option>
    <option value="" >Option 1</option>
    <option value="" >Option 2</option>
    <option value="" >Option 3</option>
  </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit-form" id="submit" value="Send Message">
  </form>
</div>
```

When i pasted code here also , the option tag is getting selected though but in my code its not getting selected!! but still here also width of the select tag is still little smaller as compared to input tag.

Now its looks like this [image: Updated Code Image]

Comment: use `box-sizing: content-box` for your select field

Comment: Yes it did worked for me but its increases the size(height) of select field.... And now its getting selected...

Comment: I think that's what you want. As mentioned by you width became little small

Comment: Yes i only wanted for a width which is working fine!! But height also git increased!! though i changed here its got effected nicely here

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/wors5fhL/

Comment: check the image attached!!

Comment: Okay!!! I got that!! But still why the color of text is getting changed!!!

Comment: And I need a button to be in center but align center is not working!!

Comment: Hey I was busy in some scrappy code ;). Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8jehLqqr/

Comment: @Master.Deep Hey, I had got the answer that day itself anyways thanks for your effort

Comment: Happy to Help :). Should I write my answer below and you mark it useful so it will help other in future

Comment: sure... i would be happy to do it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `box-sizing` property to what should be included in sizing properties (width and height)
For your issue `box-sizing: border-box` and some modification in `width` and `margin` property will do the task.

Here is the fiddle for same https://jsfiddle.net/c7Lojau2/